# mysql cli to 127.0.0.1 but redirect to 172.17.0.1

Tags: mysql, docker

I have installed mysql-client in my Mac by the following command:

```
brew install mysql-client
```

And when I run the following command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

An ERROR 1045 occured:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: NO)`

but when I use `Sequel Pro` I can login the local mysql server.

Why the 127.0.0.1 becomes 172.17.0.1 ？

---

#### MORE DETAIL INFO

I run this command on local host iTerm. I use the docker pull to pull a mysql:5.7 image from docker registry:

`docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxx -d -p 0.0.0.0:3306:3306 mysql:5.7`

And the mysql container is just running, then I use **Sequel Pro** GUI client to connect into the database in docker, and it works. And then I try to use

`brew install mysql-client`

to install the mysql command (because I want to use it to run a sql file to prepare data for my project's tests suite). after installed mysql-client, i use the command

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p`

try to connect database, but it promote the

`**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1'` (using password: NO)**.

I did **not** do any configuration for the mysql docker container.

Comment: 172.17.0.1 looks like the IP for docker bridge network. Are you trying this with docker? If so, the connection is using this gateway IP and the suggestion here(https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/275) might be helpful.

Comment: @elixir yes, I'm using docker. I just pulled a mysql:5.7 image and docker run the image. To my understanding, ``Sequel Pro`` is just a kind of mysql client. So why ··Sequel Pro`` can login into but the ``mysql`` ？

Comment: Are you running this command on the bash prompt of your Docker container? Please add the details related to the environment you are running this in along with relevant configuration details. Would be helpful in debugging.

Comment: @elixir I have updated my question to offer more detail info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hours try and search, finally I found the solution:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

you need a  `-P` parameter

Comment: DAMN.. why didnt i come across this answer 2 hours ago.